# Laravel routing does not work even when my routes exist in route:list and I have tried route:clear and route:cache

Tags: php, laravel

I have setup a route in web.php as follows

`Route::get('/blog/@{category}', 'BlogController@filterByCategory');`

And then in my BlogController.php file, I have the function:

```
use App\Category;

public function filterByCategory(Category $category)
{
      \\blah blah blah
}
```

and in my Category.php, I have changed the route key name as follows:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
        return strtolower('category_name');
}
```

where `category_name` is the column in my database where the category name after @ should be found.

This setup used to work perfectly until recently. And I don't understand why it has stopped working out of blue. No matter what I put in my URL after `/blog/@`, it always gives 404 error. I have tried my application both on Apache and Nginx, same issue.

My route **exists** in `php artisan route:list` and I have already tried both `php artisan route:cache` and `php artisan route:clear`. Both of them didn't fix the issue.

**Update:**

I commented out all other routes and kept only this route and it worked fine which means that I probably have two routes that are conflicting with each other.

Here are my other routes that are similar to this one

```
// Route::get('/blog', 'BlogController@index');
// Route::get('/blog/{short_link}', 'BlogController@show');
// Route::get('/blog/{short_link}/{string}', 'BlogController@show');
Route::get('/blog/@{category}', 'BlogController@filterByCategory');
// Route::get('/blog/keyword:{keyword}', 'BlogController@filterByKeyword');
// Route::post('/blog', 'BlogSearchController@perform');
```

Comment: `Route::get('/blog/{category}....`

Comment: @sta Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. If you are talking about @, that's intentional and that's the way I want it to work. It works fine in another route.

Comment: why you use `@` on the route?

Comment: @sta Because I want my URLs to look like that. For example, "http://www.domain.lte/blog/@science/". That's not the issue here anyway.

Comment: what the output of `public function filterByCategory(Request $request)
{
      dd($request-all()); 
}` ?

Comment: if you use `filterByCategory(Category $category)` you need to pass the `id` of model `Category`

Comment: @sta It shows the 404 page again. :( I think that means laravel is not routing to the controller at all :(

Comment: @sta No, the function getRouteKeyName() is there to enable me to use something than the ID.

Comment: @sta Nope. It doesn't work without ```@``` either. Not even if I wrote ```category={category}``` instead of ```@{category}```.

Comment: what happen with this? `Route::get(/blog/@{category}', function () { return "ok"; });` ?

Comment: @sta 404 again! :(

Comment: without `@` also get 404 ?

Comment: @sta Yup :| It's weird. I think some Laravel files might be corrupted or something. Because I'm sure it's not an Apache issue. I tested it with Nginx too :|

Comment: can you post your full route code please?

Comment: @sta I can, but it'll be too long and boring and it will waste your time. Instead of that, I commented out all routes except the line for this route and it worked fine which means that somehow I have at least two routes that are conflicting with each other. I'll try to comment out other routes that are similar to this one to find out which one is causing the conflict.

Comment: do you have a resource route with prefix `/blog` ?

Comment: @sta Yes, I do. I just copied and pasted all my routes that start with ```/blog```

Comment: You are using same URI, that's why its conflict with other route. My be its conflict with `Route::get('/blog/{short_link}', 'BlogController@show');` or `Route::get('/blog/keyword:{keyword}', 'BlogController@filterByKeyword');` all this routes URL Pattern are same

Comment: @sta Yeah. I see that now. It seems that my second route is causing it. Thank you for your time. I will be happy if you post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using same **URI** route pattern, that's why its conflict with other route. My be its conflict with `Route::get('/blog/{short_link}', 'BlogController@show');` or `Route::get('/blog/keyword:{keyword}', 'BlogController@filterByKeyword');` because  all these routes URL Pattern are same